# Logstash Configuration for CloudFoundry Loggregator

Tags: logstash, cloud-foundry

I am facing issues in setting up Logstash for Cloud Foundry what ever sources i have seen have directed me to following configuration

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
  udp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
}
filter {
if [@type] in ["syslog", "relp"] {
  # Parse Cloud Foundry logs from loggregator (syslog)
  # see https://github.com/cloudfoundry/loggregator/blob/master/src/loggregator/sinks/syslogwriter/syslog_writer.go#L156

  grok {
      match => { "syslog_procid" => "\[(?<log_source>[^/\]]+)(?:/(?<log_source_id>[^\]]+))?\]" }
      tag_on_failure => [
          "fail/logsearch-for-cloudfoundry/loggregator/_grokparsefailure"
      ]
  }

  if !("fail/logsearch-for-cloudfoundry/loggregator/_grokparsefailure" in [tags]) {
      #If it looks like JSON, it must be JSON...
      if [syslog_message] =~ /^\s*{".*}\s*$/ {
          json {
              source => "syslog_message"
          }

          # @todo seems like some messages have @timestamp in them? seems ci-specific
          date {
              match => [ "@timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
          }
      } else {
          mutate {
              add_field => [ "message", "%{syslog_message}" ]
          } 
          if [message] == "-" {
              mutate {
                  remove_field => "message"
              } 
          }
      }

      mutate {
          rename => [ "syslog_program", "@source.app_id" ]
      }

      mutate {
          add_tag => "cloudfoundry_loggregator"
          remove_field => "syslog_facility"
          remove_field => "syslog_facility_code"
          remove_field => "syslog_message"
          remove_field => "syslog_severity"
          remove_field => "syslog_severity_code"
          remove_field => "syslog5424_ver"
          remove_field => "syslog6587_msglen"
      }
  }

} 
}
output {

  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

But none of the filter is matching my logs from Cloud Foundry ,I ma getting logs like following

```
2015-08-03T09:51:15.000+00:00 [RTR] OUT mm1-spring-music.example.com - [03/08/2015:09:51:15 +0000] "GET /assets/templates/grid.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1450 "http://mm1-spring-music.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36" 10.10.125.30:37611 x_forwarded_for:"Xx.XX, 0.0.0.0" vcap_request_id:ae307d85-01c3-433b-487d-92d897dbcf99 response_time:0.002201911 app_id:08be9fc8-c7a3-4613-bf12-1a9c7d98cc27
```

KIndly suggest if some pattern already exists that can be used for parsing using Logstash

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are really using the `relp` protocol in your cloud foundry deployment manifest. The filter `if [@type] in ["syslog", "relp"]` is testing for that type.

If you are using normal UDP syslog or TCP, remove the clause from the filter. You can do this in kibana by going to the settings->objects->searches and disabling that filter or removing the `relp` condition.